# How to Edit Parent Editable Text Widget in Unreal Engine

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am very new to unreal engine, so I'm sure this is an easy question...embarrassing to even ask.

I have added an Editable Text Box into a user interface in my game. Next tot he Color and Opacity property, there is an "inherit" checkbox which I have checked.

How do I edit the parent so that all of my edit boxes have the same color? This seems like it should be obvious, and it probably is, but I have no clue how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that was easy. When it says "inherit" it does not mean object oriented inheritance, it simply inherits from its parents in the visual tree.